# use shell script to parse a multi-line value

Tags: bash, shell

How could I use shell script to parse a "keyword" from a config file like this:

```
keyword1='aaa
bbb
ccc
'
keyword2='ddd'
```

there are multi line of this value, and I want to get each line of it.

--------------------- updating

Sorry for the unclear description.
As we can see, the format of this config file is just like "key=value", I could parse a value of the keyword that has a single value easily. But I have no idea about parsing a keyword that has multi values, e.g. keyword1 as above.

Comment: Do you want each line to be in a different variable? or all of them are assigned to keyword?

Comment: thanks for the response, I want each line to be in a different variable, and then I send each of them to a function. I want that process in a loop

Comment: Is the config file valid shell syntax? Can you just do `source config.file; echo "$keyword"`?

Comment: `mapfile -t keywords <<<"$keyword"` will put all your individual lines into elements in an array named `keywords`.

Comment: this file is just a common config file, like "key=value"

Answer (score 0):

You have config.sh file that have "keyword" variable defined in it which is multi-line variable as below

config.sh

```
keyword='aaa

bbb

ccc '
```

then you can try something like below to pass every value one by one as a function argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh

function_call()
{
        # function logic
        echo $1
}

for i in $keyword
do
        function_call $i
done
```

If you do "echo $keyword", then you will get aaa bbb ccc, so can directly access them in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Given this file of `key=value`:

```
$ cat config.txt
keyword1='aaa
bbb
ccc
'
keyword2='ddd'
```

You can use `source` to associate the keys as Bash variables:

```
$ source config.txt
$ echo "$keyword2"
ddd
$ echo "$keyword1"
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Now if you want to do something with `$keyword1` use a `while` loop to read that variable line-by-line:

```
while read -r line; do 
    echo ">$line<"
done <<< "$keyword1"
>aaa<
>bbb<
>ccc<
><
```

Note there is an empty line at the end because that is the way you have it in your example.